# Unexpected implicit cast when using variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, variadic-templates, implicit-conversion

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args> class X;

template<typename T>
class X<T> {
 public:
    T value;
    X(T value_) : value(value_) {}
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class X<T, Args...> : public X<Args...> {
 public:
    T value;
    X(T value_, Args... args) : value(value_), X<Args...>(args...) {}
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T>& value_) {
    stream << value_.value;
    return stream;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, Args...>& value_) {
    stream << value_.value << " " << static_cast<X<Args...> const& >(value_);
    return stream;
}

class Person : public X<std::string, int>{
 public:
    Person(std::string name, int age) : X<std::string, int>(name, age) {}
};


int main()
{
   std::cout << Person("Me", 35) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.7.2 using 'g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp', gives the following output when executed:

```
35
```

I was expecting it to print:

```
Me 35
```

because it should have first matched the operator<< for the direct super-class of Person rather than its super-super-class, right? but that doesn't seems to have happened. It has printed only the int which is the behavior of X<int> and not both items which is the behavior of X<std::string, int>, the direct superclass. Is this expected?

Comment: I suspected and [clang++ agrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c829039e21bb5fbd): The operator `<<` in `<< static_cast<X<Args...> >(value_)` is ambiguous: Both function templates are viable, have the same rank, and as far as I can tell, neither is more specialized (despite one having an additional parameter pack!). See the note in [temp.func.order]/5

Comment: Normative reference: [temp.deduct.partial]/3 "The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done: -  In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types **for which the
function call has arguments**." [emphasis mine]

Comment: This seems a bug of gcc. VC++ 2013 CTP can produce a correct result as you expected. e.g. The output is "Me 35"

Comment: @xmllmx Great. Now we have three compilers and three different behaviours. Either it is unspecified (or undefined) in the Standard, or at least two of them have bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code as posted. Firstly the ambiguity between:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T>& value_) {
```

and:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, Args...>& value_) {
```

in the case of an empty parameter pack. This can be resolved moving to these two functions instead:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T>& value_) {
```

and:

```
template<typename T, typename T2, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, T2, Args...>& value_) {
```

Now the template matching ambiguity is resolved.

This leaves us with the second problem. This line:

```
  std::cout << Person("Me", 35) << std::endl;
```

Person provieds no implementation of operator<< so the compiler is left to convert to a type that has an implementation, in this case both `X< std::string, int >` and `X< int >` have such. However, the compiler has now way to pick between these two as the are both super classes of Person.

This can be resolved in two ways, firstly with the addition of a specific operator<< for Person:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const Person &value_) {
   stream << static_cast<const X<std::string, int, int>&>(value_);
   return stream;
}
```

which works fine but I find to be overly verbose. Alternatively, we can remove the ambiguity by removing the class hierarchy and just using a member variable to contain the 'other' vaules:

```
template<typename T>
class X<T> {
public:
    T value;
    X(T value_) : value(value_) {}
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T>& value_) {
   stream << value_.value << ".";
   return stream;
}


// Empty arg packs will match ambiguously with nothing so make sure the empty pack case is distanct from the base case

template<typename T, typename T2, typename... Args>
class X<T, T2, Args...> {
public:
   T value;
   X<T2, Args...> superValue;
   X(T value_, T2 arg, Args... args) : value(value_), superValue(arg, args...) {}
};

template<typename T, typename T2, typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, T2, Args...>& value_) {
   stream << value_.value << "," << value_.superValue;
   return stream;
}
```

Now Person can only be implicitly cast to `X < std::string,int >` and nothing else and there is no amibguity. Recent g++'s and clang's are both compile this without issue.

As to whether nothing should match an empty arg pack in template resolution or whether a more direct base class should match in favour of a less direct one in conversion resolution, I leave to people more versed in the c++ standard than myself.

Comment: I gave it a +1, it works is worth a lot.  And doesn't require the bounce I did.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args> class X;

template<typename T>
class X<T> {
 public:
    T value;
    explicit X(T value_) : value(value_) {}
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class X<T, Args...> : public X<Args...> {
 public:
    T value;
    explicit X(T value_, Args... args) : X<Args...>(args...), value(value_) {}
};
```

This type lets us use tag dispatching to select an overload based on the number of arguments to `X`:

```
template<std::size_t> struct compile_time_size {};
```

Here are 3 overloads.  The first errors on 0 arguments, the second handles 1, and the third handles `N`:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& output_helper(std::ostream&, const X<Ts...>&, compile_time_size<0>) = delete;

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::ostream& output_helper(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, Ts...>& value, compile_time_size<1>)
{
    stream << value.value;
    return stream;
}
template<typename T, typename... Ts, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& output_helper(std::ostream& stream, const X<T, Ts...>& value, compile_time_size<N>)
{
    stream << value.value << " " << static_cast< X<Ts...> const& >(value);
    return stream;
}
```

Our `<<` is now just one overload, which makes reasoning about it easy.  It then dispatches to the above helper functions, passing the length explicitly.  They redispatch back down to `<<` using ADL to find the function declared after themselves:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const X<Ts...>& value) {
    return output_helper( stream, value, compile_time_size<sizeof...(Ts)>() );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/040e117f04f2aac3)

Comment: *"And functions prefer to matxh without ... if possible."* I don't quite understand what you mean with that. Your solution should work, as it disambiguates between the two function templates by making them mutually exclusively viable for certain numbers of template parameters.

Comment: As mentioned in my comments to the OP, coliru's clang++3.5 thinks the call via `<< static_cast<X<Args...> >(value_)` is ambiguous. I.e. neither is more specialized, the empty parameter pack seems to be irrelevant for overload resolution.

Comment: @dyp clang's overload resolution code seems to ignore empty parameter packs: I am unsure they are right.  I am basing my belief that the empty packs demote the overload choice below otherwise matching overloads.  I won't be at a real computer for a bit however.

Comment: So, it seems to me that this solution isn't really generic, what if Person extended X<std::string,int,int>? wouldn't we just get back to the same problem again?

Comment: @PeteFordham You should have two overloads: one that takes exactly 1 argument, and another that takes 2 or more.  The overload taking 1 or more should be deleted.  As an aside, the cast should be a cast-to-`const`-reference, not a cast-to-value.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Yes, I've made the changes you suggest. I only have the two overloads you list and this works well for the X<std::string,int> case, but when I make Person extend X<std::string, int,int> instead my test program only prints the value of the final int and nothing else. http://pastebin.com/y47BLLYv

Comment: @PeteFordham Well, when I tested it on ideone, gcc refused to ever guess what `T...` was.  Maybe a bug in that version of gcc.  I decided to go for a different approach, which (as linked above) works fine in `clang`, and gets rid of most of the overload-resolution-based-on-`...` issues.